# 'None' is not a callable or a dot-notation path

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.9.4 and python 3.4.3 on ubuntu 14.04 to build a blog but I get the following error. I don't know how I did it, it just didn't work.

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /
'None' is not a callable or a dot-notation path
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.9.4
Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
'None' is not a callable or a dot-notation path
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in get_callable, line 102
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3.4
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/gaoliang/Desktop/my_blog',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/stevedore-1.12.0-py3.4.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/six-1.10.0-py3.4.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pbr-1.8.1-py3.4.egg',
 '/home/gaoliang/Desktop/my_blog',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 16 Apr 2016 20:31:57 +0800
```

I don't konw why the django point out that I have an error in the html.

```
Error during template rendering

In template /home/gaoliang/Desktop/my_blog/blog/templates/index.html, error at line 16
'None' is not a callable or a dot-notation path
6   {% block content %}
7       
8       <div class="container">
9
10          <div class="row">
11              <div class="col-md-8">
12
13                  <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
14                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
15                              aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
16                      <p align="center">************* welcome  *****************</p>
17                  </div>
18                  {% for article in article_list %}
19                      {% include 'article_display.html' %}
20                      <br>
21                  {% endfor %}
22                  <nav>
23                      <ul class="pager">
24                          <li class="current">{{ object_list.number }} / {{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}</li>
25                          {% if object_list.has_previous %}
26                              <li class="previous"><a href="?page={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}"><span
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Please reduce code removing unrelated lines and add clear description what you expect and what you get.

Comment: In addition, 'ViewDoesNotExist at /' indicates an error in urls.py.

Comment: what you really ought to post is the bit of code that renders this template